# How to send an email from an outlook office add on?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to build an outlook add on, using react. I looked everywhere trying to find something that uses the mailbox in which the addon has been opened from, to programmatically send an email to a specified user.

Something similar to the google's command:

```
  GmailApp.createDraft(e.parameters.address, e.parameters.subject, e.parameters.body, {
    htmlBody: e.parameters.body,
    name: 'Automatic Sender'
  }).send();
```

Is the mail-sending process available on outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item only. `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for creating and sending emails programmatically.

In Outlook add-ins you may consider using `EWS`, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information. Also you may take a look at the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) as a possible workaround.