# Outlook Web Add-In - Office-JS - Sort Incoming E-Mail

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've got a macro for sorting my incoming e-mail that I considered converting to Office-JS. I just saw [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574707/how-to-send-an-email-from-an-outlook-office-add-on) and the answer stated --

> Outlook web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item only

Does that mean my idea of an Add-In that sorts e-mail is unfeasible currently? Can I make an Add-In that constantly runs and redirects incoming e-mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run add-in(s) only on a particular item(mail/calendar event). The Add-in framework does not support a trigger based on the incoming emails.

Comment: Thats very disappointing. I have a VBA macro to sort my incoming mail based on Domain/User e-mails and Subject keywords and its much better then Rules, but would love to port to JS. Anyway, thanks for the official answer..

Comment: You can port your VBA macros to a VSTO add-in if you need to deploy your solution to a wide public. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022) for more information.